# Find the rank of adj$A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix of order $n$ of rank $n-2$; $n>2$, then what is the rank of adj$(A)$.? My assumption is $A*\text{adj}(A)=\det(A)*I$. Now $\det(A)=0$. So $A*\text{adj}(A)=0$.But I cannot go beyond it.

Comment: Use the definition of "adj" and rank.

Answer (score 4):

Each entry of $\text{adj}(A)$ is the algebraic cofactor of $A$, which is the signed determinant of an $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ submatrix of $A$. Since $\text{rank}(A) = n - 2 < n - 1$, each entry of $\text{adj}(A)$ is $0$, therefore, $\text{adj}(A)$ is a zero matrix, which has rank $0$.